# What is the storage format of an image in Acumatica?

Tags: image, acumatica

I am trying to upload images from Acumatica to a third party website and it requires the image data to be in base-64 format.

What format does Acumatica store images in on the database?

Answer (score 1):

The images and all attachments are stored in raw binary format. The files are stored in the Data field, of type varbinary(max), which is in the UploadFileRevision table.

Base 64 is not a file format, but rather a way to encode binary data in a string format. More information on Base 64 as well as a sample implementation in Java (should work almost unmodified in C#) is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64